Eigenvalue Problem with Pseudospectral Chebyshev Polynomials
I am solving a linear 4th Order Eigenvalue ODE (Euler-Bernoulli Beam):
$$
{\frac{d^{4}w}{dx^{4}}} = - \alpha {\frac{d^{2}w}{dx^{2}}}
$$
The method I used was to apply a truncated spectral expansion ($N$ Chebyshev basis functions) for $w$ and then choose $N - 4$ Gauss-Lobotto Collocation Points within $(-1, 1)$ for each of the LHS and RHS operator. I then impose 4 boundary conditions in the last four rows of the matrix using the n-th order differential value for Chebyshev Polynomials known from [1] at $x = -1$ or $x = 1$ leaving the corresponding rows of the RHS operator as a row of zeros.
I then solve the generalized eigenvalue problem to obtain $\alpha$ and the eigenmode shapes. I tested this particular formulation against four cases,

Simply Supported $T_n(-1)=T_n(1)=0$ and $T^{''}_n(-1)=T^{''}_n(1)=0$
Clamped-Clamped $T_n(-1)=T_n(1)=0$ and $T^{'}_n(-1)=T^{'}_n(1)=0$
Simply-Clamped $T_n(-1)=T_n(1)=0$ and $T^{''}_n(-1)=T^{'}_n(1)=0$
Clamped-Free $T_n(-1)=T^{'}_n(-1)=0$ and $T^{'''}_n(1)=T^{''}_n(1)=0$

My code gives the correct results for cases (1), (2), (3) and fails to produce consistent eigenvalues for (4).
I have checked for up to $N = 40$ polynomials (basically the point till where the matrix condition number is larger than the machine epsilon).
I am quite certain that I am missing something very fundamental here but I am not sure what. I have also followed another paper [2] which describes using the Ultraspherical Spectral method, but I obtained the same pattern of results, (1), (2), (3) were correct (4) was improper, weirdly enough I found that the eigenvalues sometimes were the same wrong values even though it was a different method (and entirely different code that called none of the functions or libraries from the pseudospectral code).
I have tried to use a different eigenvalue library (LAPACK (QR Method), ARPACK (Arnoldi Restarted Algorithm), SLEPc (Krylov Subspace Methods), and even exported the matrix to MATLAB to verify). I am at a loss here and I find this anomaly very interesting.
(I have also tried to use MP-LAPACK with extended precision with the Ultraspeherical Method but the eigenvalues are failing to converge for (4) even $N > 256$)
[1] - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials - Section "Differentiation and Integration"
[2] - https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.1347

How are you imposing the boundary conditions?

@nicoguaro $A_{ij} = T^{p}j(\pm 1)$ where $i$ corresponds to the last 4 rows of A (the LHS operator). On the other side $B{ij}=0$ where B is the RHS matrix. The formula for $T^{p}_j(\pm 1)$ is taken from [1] as mentioned in the question.
